# React Router Location Object Key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Can anyone just give me a definition of what the `key` is within the location object from react router? All I see is that sometimes it has a string as its value. I have looked around the source code and the internet and I still don't have a solid understanding of what it represents.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem it is the route unique identifier. Since react-router uses components and this can be nested at any level and composed in any way it would seem react-router creates a key for the route after it has been mounted